# how to fix the size of the properties/preferences dialogs of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dimension

After I adjust some properties of some project in Eclipse, next time I open the properties window it will locate the item that I modified last time and its size will fit to the item accordingly.

But sometimes the page for the item is so large that the whole dialog becomes very big and fill the whole screen of my laptop.

Same thing happens to the Preferences dialog. Is there any way to fix the size of the properties/preferences dialogs? Say I want it always be 600 X 800 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

No, not with Eclipse built-in features. Depending on your operating system, you could always hack a small script for something like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (Windows only) to resize that window whenever it appears on the screen.